# Javascript error "Cannot read property"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

```
  var dataLayer =[{
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      }
    }
  }
}];
```

I am trying to add products name and price dynamically into the products.
Here is the code:

```
$('.to-buy').click(function() {
    $('.sed').each(function() {
        var product_name = $(this).find('h5').text();
        var product_price = $(this).parent().siblings(".cost").text();
        dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products.push({
            "name" : product_name ,
            "price" :product_price
        }); 
    });
});
```

But I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'purchase' of undefined".
I am expecting datalayer as below:

```
 'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345', 
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
        'price': '15.25'
       },
       {
        'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
        'price': '33.75',
       }]
    }
  }
```

Any help is accepted. Thank you.

Comment: means `dataLayer.ecommerce` is undefined. If you look at it, dataLayer is an array...

Comment: try dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.products.push

Comment: `dataLayer` is an array, There is no `products` property in the `purchase` object so you have to add it first

Answer (score 2):

Your `dataLayer` is an array, so trying to access the property `ecommerce` of an array returns `undefined`. And accessing purchase of undefined throws an exception.

Use `dataLayer[0].ecommerce` instead, or change your dataLayer to an object like this:

```
 var dataLayer ={
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Further your `dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products.push` is accessing `products` inside purchace but I dont see any products inside your dataLayer.

Add property `products` to your `dataLayer` object

```
var dataLayer ={
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      products:[] // Your are missing this
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two problem, first **dataLayer** is an array so you have to access datalayer's first element. the another is you have to create a **product** property inside **purchase**

```
dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.products =[{
  "name":product_name ,
  "price" :product_price
 }];
```

OR

```
dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.products =[];
dataLayer[0].ecommerce.purchase.products.push({
  "name":product_name ,
  "price" :product_price
 });
```

any of the two from the above must work